# Filling Time_Dimension?

Tags: sql, oracle, calendar, etl, business-intelligence

I wrote this script but it doesn't work. I don't get any error message, it just hangs, could you please help me out?

```
DECLARE
    vYear_ID VARCHAR(4);
    vQuarter CHARACTER(6);
    vMonth_Num SMALLINT;
    vMonth_Name VARCHAR(20);
    vWeekday_Num SMALLINT;
    vWeekday_Name VARCHAR(20); 
    vStartDate Date := '01/01/1998';
    vEndDate Date := '31/12/2002';
    vDate_ID Date;
    vDate_ID := vStartDate;

BEGIN

    WHILE vDate_ID < vEndDate 
    LOOP
        vYear_ID := TO_CHAR(vDate_ID,'YYYY');
        vQuarter := TO_CHAR(vDate_ID,'YYYY')||'Q'||TO_CHAR(vDate_ID,'Q');
        vMonth_Num := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(vDate_ID,'MM'));
        vMonth_Name := TO_CHAR(vDate_ID,'Month');
        vWeekday_Num := TO_NUMBER(TRIM(leading '0' FROM TO_CHAR(vDate_ID,'D')));
        vWeekday_Name := TO_CHAR(vDate_ID,'Day');

        INSERT INTO Time_Dim VALUES (vDate_ID, vYear_ID, vQuarter, vMonth_Name, vWeekday_Name, vMonth_Num, );

        vDate_ID = to_date(vDate_ID,'DD/MM/YYYY')+1

    END LOOP;

END;
```

I have to use the While Loop and not a For.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "does not work" is not particularly informative.  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?

Comment: You have a trailing comma - " vMonth_Num, );"  BTW, you have a reputation > 1, so I would expect you would know how to ask a proper question.

Comment: To follow up on OldProgrammer's comment please at least include the error message when posting a question with an error. In Oracle the error tells you the line number, and should easily have identified the trailing comma and the missing semi-colon `vDate_ID = to_date(vDate_ID,'DD/MM/YYYY')+1`. Please make an attempt to solve this yourself before asking a question.

Comment: I don't get any error message, it just hangs in there, that is why i didn't include any in my question, sorry for the inconvenience .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't address the exact question.  But as the actual question is a dreary "guess the compilation error" I have elected to answer a more interesting question instead :)

```
INSERT INTO Time_Dim VALUES 
    (vDate_ID, vYear_ID, vQuarter, vMonth_Name, vMonth_Num, vWeekday_Name, vWeekday_Num)
with dt as ( select date '1998-01-01' as start_dt
                    , date '2002-12-31' as end_dt 
             from dual )
     , ths as ( select start_dt + ( level - 1) as id_date
                from dt
                connect by level <= ( end_dt - start_dt ) + 1
              )
select id_date
       , to_char(id_date, 'YYYY')
       , trim(to_char(id_date, 'YYYY'))||'Q'||to_char(id_date, 'Q')
       , to_char(id_date, 'Month')
       , to_number(to_char(id_date, 'MM'))
       , to_char(id_date, 'Day')
       , to_number(to_char(id_date, 'D'))
from ths;
```

Here's [a SQL Fiddle for the SELECT part of the statement](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80134/13).

Comment: Thanks a lot APC-sama :), you are a life saver, I am not good with PL/SQL, but this one would do it for me, thanks again ^^.